# Is it possible to make different gunicorn workers handle different groups of urls?

Tags: multiprocessing, gunicorn, httpserver, uvicorn

There is an application in Django + Gunicorn (with Uvicorn workers) + Nginx. The application is built WITHOUT the use of multiprocessing and microservices (yet).

As expected, the use of multiple workers leads to errors due to the lack of shared RAM.

Is it possible to configure Gunicorn (or similar servers) in such a way that different workers only handle their own groups of urls?

For example:

1. Worker №1 handle only urls started with '/group1/...' (for big files, static).
2. Worker №2 handle only urls started with '/group2/...' (for user data calculations).

Feel free to call the question stupid. And thanks for any ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of WSGI middleware to handle the mapping of routes.

Here is an example: https://github.com/lukearno/selector

Gunicorn just handles management of worker processes for a WSGI server.